# Error Invalid csrContent when creating a free provisioning profile in Xcode 11

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I'm getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRs04.png) when trying to create a free provisioning profile in Xcode.
When i press manage certificates in Xcode preferences, i am getting the same error.
I have tried to reinstall Apple WorldWide Developer Relations Certification Authority in keychain access but it didn't changed anything.

When i run the following command : `security find-identity -v -p codesigning`, i get this message : `0 valid identities found`

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Today I had this problem and seemed some problem with my profile.
If you go to Preferences > Accounts > Your Personal Account > Manage certificates
I you try to create a new certificate you will receive the same csr Error.

So I remove my account, restart xcode and add again my account, and then I could create the certificate for my account and compile the app.

Hope this helps ;).